# Echo command hangs when writing to serial device

Tags: command-line, bash, serial-port

I have a serial device set to raw mode with `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 raw`. When i try to send any data through it with `echo 'hello' > /dev/ttyS0`, following happens:

- No data is recieved by the other side; oscilloscope shows no data is being sent
- No prompt appears for approximately 40 seconds, terminal seems to be hanging

What could be the reason for this behaviour?

P.S. The serial port settings as output with `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -a` are:

> speed 9600 baud; stty: /dev/ttyS0 line = 0; intr = ^C; quit = ^\;
>   erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = < undef>; eol2 = < undef>;
>   swtch = < undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase
>   = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
>   -parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
>   -ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
>   -opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
>   -isig -icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search for the possible reason, i happened across the solution. It had to do with a certain error during initialisation of my hardware under linux. Solution was to manually (well, from a program run with elevation) set a flag that controlled signal level for interruptions.

After that was set, serial port started working as expected.

I have found solution here: [linux.org forums](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/linux-hardware/12336599/page1). It references [superiotool](https://github.com/wt/coreboot/tree/master/util/superiotool) as inspiration

Answer (score 1):

If one uses RTS/CTS hardware flow control then the serial will block waiting for the RTS (Ready-To-Send).  You probably want to enable software flow control instead by disabling CTS and RTS:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -crtscts
```

Comment: That did not help, sadly